# Effect of choosing a linear model with only weights but with an extra X entry that is always set to 1

Tags: regression, linear-model

If we are to choose  a linear model with only weights but augment X with an extra entry that is always set to 1, what effect does it have on the assumption and estimation on the resulting linear model.

i.e when compared to a linear model with an intercept.

If one could also explain when such a model is preferred over the intercept included model, would make it clear.